# Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation error in prod server

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I am getting some errors in production box which we are not getting in our local testing. We are not using any modal dialogue popuups or not any window message popups in entire popups. Is that causing because of any response.redirect? Here is my server eventlog. Can anybody tell me what causing this issue?

```
 Log Name:      Application
Source:        ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0
Date:          4/11/2011 8:44:42 AM
Event ID:      1309
Task Category: Web Event
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      PACDCPCCOMA01.cable.comcast.com
Description:
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 4/11/2011 8:44:42 AM 
Event time (UTC): 4/11/2011 12:44:42 PM 
Event ID: a66a8c24117e49d4979975e947bfe021 
Event sequence: 49560 
Event occurrence: 8 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-1-129469890006189836 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\ 
    Machine name: PACDCPCCOMA01 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 4752 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\Classic .NET AppPool 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application. 

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://ccom/Default.aspx 
    Request path: /Default.aspx 
    User host address: 10.164.74.56 
    User: CABLE\awitko200 
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Negotiate 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\Classic .NET AppPool 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 18 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\Classic .NET AppPool 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
   at Syncfusion.Core.Licensing.FusionLicenseProvider.GetLicense(LicenseContext context, Type type, Object instance, Boolean allowExceptions)
   at System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.ValidateInternalRecursive(LicenseContext context, Type type, Object instance, Boolean allowExceptions, License& license, String& licenseKey)
   at System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.ValidateInternal(Type type, Object instance, Boolean allowExceptions, License& license)
   at System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.Validate(Type type, Object instance)
   at Syncfusion.Core.Licensing.LicensedWebComponent..ctor(Type type)
   at Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Tools.Common.CoreUtilities.ValidateLicense(Type typeToValidate)
   at Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Tools.AutoCompleteTextBox..ctor()
   at ASP.default_aspx.__BuildControltxtDivSales() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\Default.aspx:line 1226
   at ASP.default_aspx.__BuildControl__control6(Control __ctrl) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\Default.aspx:line 1208
   at System.Web.UI.CompiledTemplateBuilder.InstantiateIn(Control container)
   at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.CreateContents()
   at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.set_ContentTemplate(ITemplate value)
   at ASP.default_aspx.__BuildControlupSales() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\Default.aspx:line 1208
   at ASP.default_aspx.__BuildControl__control5(Control __ctrl) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\Default.aspx:line 1203
   at System.Web.UI.CompiledTemplateBuilder.InstantiateIn(Control container)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.SingleTemplateContainer.InstantiateTemplate()
   at Telerik.Web.UI.SingleTemplateContainer.set_Template(ITemplate value)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadWindow.set_ContentTemplate(ITemplate value)
   at ASP.default_aspx.__BuildControlwinSearchSurveys() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\Default.aspx:line 1203
   at ASP.default_aspx.__BuildControl__control4(WindowCollection __ctrl) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\Default.aspx:line 1201
   at ASP.default_aspx.__BuildControlRadWinMgr() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\Default.aspx:line 1201
   at ASP.default_aspx.__BuildControlContent2(Control __ctrl) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\Default.aspx:line 658
   at System.Web.UI.CompiledTemplateBuilder.InstantiateIn(Control container)
   at ASP.masterpage_master.__BuildControlPagePlaceholder() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\MasterPage.master:line 296
   at ASP.masterpage_master.__BuildControlfrm() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\MasterPage.master:line 65
   at ASP.masterpage_master.__BuildControlTree(masterpage_master __ctrl) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\MasterPage.master:line 1
   at ASP.masterpage_master.FrameworkInitialize() in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\b6b42b42\a011ed90\App_Web_r97r-sw3.4.cs:line 0
   at System.Web.UI.UserControl.InitializeAsUserControlInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.get_Master()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)


Custom event details: 

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32768">1309</EventID>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>3</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2011-04-11T12:44:42.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>15385</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>PACDCPCCOMA01.cable.comcast.com</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>3005</Data>
    <Data>An unhandled exception has occurred.</Data>
    <Data>4/11/2011 8:44:42 AM</Data>
    <Data>4/11/2011 12:44:42 PM</Data>
    <Data>a66a8c24117e49d4979975e947bfe021</Data>
    <Data>49560</Data>
    <Data>8</Data>
    <Data>0</Data>
    <Data>/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-1-129469890006189836</Data>
    <Data>Full</Data>
    <Data>/</Data>
    <Data>C:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\</Data>
    <Data>PACDCPCCOMA01</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>4752</Data>
    <Data>w3wp.exe</Data>
    <Data>IIS APPPOOL\Classic .NET AppPool</Data>
    <Data>InvalidOperationException</Data>
    <Data>Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.</Data>
    <Data>http://ccom/Default.aspx</Data>
    <Data>/Default.aspx</Data>
    <Data>10.164.74.56</Data>
    <Data>CABLE\awitko200</Data>
    <Data>True</Data>
    <Data>Negotiate</Data>
    <Data>IIS APPPOOL\Classic .NET AppPool</Data>
    <Data>18</Data>
    <Data>IIS APPPOOL\Classic .NET AppPool</Data>
    <Data>False</Data>
    <Data>   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
   at Syncfusion.Core.Licensing.FusionLicenseProvider.GetLicense(LicenseContext context, Type type, Object instance, Boolean allowExceptions)
   at System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.ValidateInternalRecursive(LicenseContext context, Type type, Object instance, Boolean allowExceptions, License&amp; license, String&amp; licenseKey)
   at System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.ValidateInternal(Type type, Object instance, Boolean allowExceptions, License&amp; license)
   at System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.Validate(Type type, Object instance)
   at Syncfusion.Core.Licensing.LicensedWebComponent..ctor(Type type)
   at Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Tools.Common.CoreUtilities.ValidateLicense(Type typeToValidate)
   at Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Tools.AutoCompleteTextBox..ctor()
   at ASP.default_aspx.__BuildControltxtDivSales() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\Default.aspx:line 1226
   at ASP.default_aspx.__BuildControl__control6(Control __ctrl) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\Default.aspx:line 1208
   at System.Web.UI.CompiledTemplateBuilder.InstantiateIn(Control container)
   at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.CreateContents()
   at System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.set_ContentTemplate(ITemplate value)
   at ASP.default_aspx.__BuildControlupSales() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\Default.aspx:line 1208
   at ASP.default_aspx.__BuildControl__control5(Control __ctrl) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\Default.aspx:line 1203
   at System.Web.UI.CompiledTemplateBuilder.InstantiateIn(Control container)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.SingleTemplateContainer.InstantiateTemplate()
   at Telerik.Web.UI.SingleTemplateContainer.set_Template(ITemplate value)
   at Telerik.Web.UI.RadWindow.set_ContentTemplate(ITemplate value)
   at ASP.default_aspx.__BuildControlwinSearchSurveys() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\Default.aspx:line 1203
   at ASP.default_aspx.__BuildControl__control4(WindowCollection __ctrl) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\Default.aspx:line 1201
   at ASP.default_aspx.__BuildControlRadWinMgr() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\Default.aspx:line 1201
   at ASP.default_aspx.__BuildControlContent2(Control __ctrl) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\Default.aspx:line 658
   at System.Web.UI.CompiledTemplateBuilder.InstantiateIn(Control container)
   at ASP.masterpage_master.__BuildControlPagePlaceholder() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\MasterPage.master:line 296
   at ASP.masterpage_master.__BuildControlfrm() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\MasterPage.master:line 65
   at ASP.masterpage_master.__BuildControlTree(masterpage_master __ctrl) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\OM\MasterPage.master:line 1
   at ASP.masterpage_master.FrameworkInitialize() in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\b6b42b42\a011ed90\App_Web_r97r-sw3.4.cs:line 0
   at System.Web.UI.UserControl.InitializeAsUserControlInternal()
   at System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.get_Master()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Syncfusion controls can't find a valid license on your server, and **are attempting to show a dialog informing you as such**. The error appears to be originating from `Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Tools.AutoCompleteTextbox`.

[You might find this SyncFusion document helpful.](http://help.syncfusion.com/ug_82/common/HowDoIRemoveTheLicensingErrorPopupThatOccursEachTimeIRunMyApplication.html)

The relevant part of your stack trace is:

```
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner) 
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog() at Syncfusion.Core.Licensing.FusionLicenseProvider.GetLicense(LicenseContext context, Type type, Object instance, Boolean allowExceptions) 
at System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.ValidateInternalRecursive(LicenseContext context, Type type, Object instance, Boolean allowExceptions, License& license, String& licenseKey)
```

....

```
at System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.ValidateInternal(Type type, Object instance, Boolean allowExceptions, License& license) 
at System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.Validate(Type type, Object instance) 
at Syncfusion.Core.Licensing.LicensedWebComponent..ctor(Type type) 
at Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Tools.Common.CoreUtilities.ValidateLicense(Type typeToValidate) 
at Syncfusion.Web.UI.WebControls.Tools.AutoCompleteTextBox..ctor() 
at ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some controls creating the problem, check this stack trace information Stack trace:

> at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window
>   owner) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
>   at
>   Syncfusion.Core.Licensing.FusionLicenseProvider.GetLicense(LicenseContext
>   context, Type type, Object instance,
>   Boolean allowExceptions) at
>   System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.ValidateInternalRecursive(LicenseContext
>   context, Type type, Object instance,
>   Boolean allowExceptions, License&
>   license, String& licenseKey)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using a licensed component that is trying to show a license warning?

As per your stack trace:

```
 Syncfusion.Core.Licensing.FusionLicenseProvider.GetLicense(...)
```